# Kafka spring integeration how to hanlde if Kafka server is down

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I have a web application which sends kafka messages by reading some values from request. How do I send error status if my kafka server is down. Right now on server down cases prodcuer continously tries to connect and logs the below error infinitely.

Error :

```
14:56:10.181 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.a.kafka.common.network.Selector - Error in I/O with localhost/127.0.0.1
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Producer configuration is :

```
<int:channel id="inputToKafka">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
        auto-startup="true"
        kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
        channel="inputToKafka"  >
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="10" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5" keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500"/>

<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="localhost:9092"
                                          key-class-type="java.lang.String"
                                          value-class-type="java.lang.String"
                                          sync="true"
                                          send-timeout="10"
                                          topic="test"
                                          key-encoder="kafkaEncoder"
                                          value-encoder="kafkaEncoder"
                                          compression-type="none"/>
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>
<bean id="kafkaEncoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringEncoder">
</bean>
<bean id="valueEncoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="com.fastretailing.catalogPlatformSCMProducer.model.ProducerMessage" />
</bean>
```

Sending code is :

```
 ProducerMessage k = list.get(0);
    boolean status = false;
    try {
        status = inputToKafka.send(
                MessageBuilder.withPayload(k.getJsonString(k))
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, k.getFeedName())  // Note: the header was `messageKey` in earlier versions
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "test")       // Note: the header was `topic` in earlier versions
                        .build()
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println(status);
    if (!status){
        System.out.println("errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
    }
```

I always get the status as true. Even when the kafka server is down. And the above connection refused error continuously shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the poller and the `<queue/>` element from `inputToKafka`.

All that status is saying is that the message was enqueued in the channel ok.

Making it a `DirectChannel` (by removing the queue) means the adapter send will run on the calling thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gary.. I will try this and update soon.

Comment: I tried like you said. But when I put kafka server down for exception handling testing ,My server continuously logs the below exception. How can I catch this and give an error response ? 

  

    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

Comment: That's coming from underlying client trying to reconnect - by default he does so every 10ms - you can increase it or change the `reconnect.backoff.ms` property, or you can increase the log level for that class to ERROR. Also, by default, the exception won't be thrown until 60 seconds later; so reduce that delay, I changed the [sample app](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/commit/52c8890e7abb7ac55d70114f4499e0ce9c24b6fa) and tested and it worked as expected. See the [kafka docs](http://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html) for more information about these properties.

Comment: Hi @BillGoldberg
Were you able to detect the server failure in the code?
I am also facing the same issue. Please let me know the solution that you implemented.